# Howto install psycopg2 in virtualenv with mx support?

Tags: python, postgresql, pip, virtualenv, psycopg2

I have a virtualenv `venv` where I installed `mx-base` and `psycopg2` with pip:

```
$ pip freeze | grep "psyco\|mx"
egenix-mx-base==3.2.8
psycopg2==2.6
```

The basics of `psycopg2` works but when using extensions I get exceptions like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my_proj/my_code.py", line 32, in <module>
    register_types()
  File "/my_proj/my_code.py", line 28, in register_types 
    psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2._psycopg.MXDATETIME)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MXDATETIME'
```

Or:

```
ulf@kalla:~(0)(venv)$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>> #Use mx.DateTime instead of pythons datetime, for compability reasons.
... psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2._psycopg.MXDATETIME)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MXDATETIME'
>>>
```

It seems that the installed version of `psycopg2` lacks the `mx`-support.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to build psycopg2 on your own, download the tar.gz, unzip, and then find the setup.cfg file, modify the mx_include parameter to be /lib/python2.7/site-packages/mx/DateTime/mxDateTime and then

python setup.py build_ext install